# Ported PHP cipher behaves differently than its Python counterpart

Tags: php, python-3.x, encryption

a while ago I made a script in Python that took a string and moved all character to the right by comparing it to an array of characters.

The Python code:

```
def Cypher(self,StrMsg,StrCode,IntCypher):
        self.StrNwMsg = ""
        IntI = IntCypher
        for IntO in range(0,len(StrMsg)):
            IntI += 1
            for IntL in range(0,len(StrCode)):
                if StrMsg[IntO] == StrCode[IntL]:
                    if(IntL + IntI) < len(StrCode):
                        self.StrNwMsg += StrCode[IntL + IntI]
                    else:
                        while (IntL + IntI) >= len(StrCode):
                            IntI -= len(StrCode)
                        self.StrNwMsg += StrCode[IntL + IntI]
        return self.StrNwMsg
```

The PHP code:

```
function Cyther($Msg,$StrCode,$IntCypther){
    $NewMsg = "";
    $I = $IntCypther;
    for($O = 0; $O <= strlen($Msg)-1;$O++){
        $I += 1;
        for($L = 0; $L <= count($StrCode)-1;$L++){
            if($Msg[$O] == $StrCode[$L]){
                if(($L+$I) < (count($StrCode)-1)){
                    $NewMsg .= $StrCode[$L+$I];
                }else{
                    while(($L + $I) >= (count($StrCode)-1)){
                        $I -= count($StrCode)-1;
                    }
                    $NewMsg .= $StrCode[$L+$I];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $NewMsg;
}
```

but i wanted to make it in PHP to store passwords because you can change IntI into the users ID so there data being store will always have a pretty well hidden password. but the PHP code doesn't work. here is the array that they both use: (I removed the brackets to get rid of any confusion. the array is 1 dimensional)

```
"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J",
"K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T",
"U","V","W","X","Y","Z","a","b","c","d",
"e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n",
"o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x",
"y","z","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8",
 "9","0",".",",","'","?","!"," ","_","-"
```

Ok so, when I enter 'Example', the PHP and Pyhton script both return 'P0n152v' but when i enter '0A', PHP return 'D' and this error:

```
Undefined offset: -57 in /var/www/Test_Page/Encryption/Encrypt.php on line 25
```

the error is referring to this line of code `$NewMsg .= $StrCode[$L+$I];` because `$L + $I` being out of the bounds of `$StrCode` array. but i dont have this issue in the identical Python code.

and Python return 'CM' which is what they should both return. i have rewrote this code at least 6 times now and I can't tell why im getting this issues. anyone know why im having this issues.

just to add the IntCypther variable is 10 for both the PHP and Python script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure how Python works, but you can't indefinitely add or subtract from the index of an array in PHP. Once you get to 0 and start subtracting more (assuming the indexes are zero-based and numerical), you're going to get an undefined offset error because that index doesn't exist. The same happens if you increase it more than the maximum index. You might want to do something like modulo to make sure that the value is always in the range of the indexes of the array.

I whipped up a quick PHP script that should do this:

```
function Offset($offset) {
    $array = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J",
    "K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T",
    "U","V","W","X","Y","Z","a","b","c","d",
    "e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n",
    "o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x",
    "y","z","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8",
    "9","0",".",",","'","?","!","@","_","-"];

    // Make sure the offset is a +/- value of the indexes of $array
    // by taking the modulo
    $offset = $offset % (count($array)-1) ;

    // If it is a negative number, subtract it from the end instead
    if ($offset < 0) {
        $offset = count($array)-1 + $offset;
    }

    // Get the index from your array
    return $array[$offset];
}


for ($i=-200; $i<200; $i++) {
    echo "$i => ".(Offset($i))."<br>";
}
```

This outputs:

```
-200 => K
-199 => L
-198 => M
-197 => N
-196 => O
-195 => P
-194 => Q
-193 => R
-192 => S
-191 => T
-190 => U
-189 => V
-188 => W
-187 => X
-186 => Y
-185 => Z
-184 => a
-183 => b
-182 => c
-181 => d
-180 => e
-179 => f
-178 => g
-177 => h
-176 => i
-175 => j
-174 => k
-173 => l
-172 => m
-171 => n
-170 => o
-169 => p
-168 => q
-167 => r
-166 => s
-165 => t
-164 => u
-163 => v
-162 => w
-161 => x
-160 => y
-159 => z
-158 => 1
-157 => 2
-156 => 3
-155 => 4
-154 => 5
-153 => 6
-152 => 7
-151 => 8
-150 => 9
-149 => 0
-148 => .
-147 => ,
-146 => '
-145 => ?
-144 => !
-143 => @
-142 => _
-141 => -
-140 => A
-139 => B
-138 => C
-137 => D
-136 => E
-135 => F
-134 => G
-133 => H
-132 => I
-131 => J
-130 => K
-129 => L
-128 => M
-127 => N
-126 => O
-125 => P
-124 => Q
-123 => R
-122 => S
-121 => T
-120 => U
-119 => V
-118 => W
-117 => X
-116 => Y
-115 => Z
-114 => a
-113 => b
-112 => c
-111 => d
-110 => e
-109 => f
-108 => g
-107 => h
-106 => i
-105 => j
-104 => k
-103 => l
-102 => m
-101 => n
-100 => o
-99 => p
-98 => q
-97 => r
-96 => s
-95 => t
-94 => u
-93 => v
-92 => w
-91 => x
-90 => y
-89 => z
-88 => 1
-87 => 2
-86 => 3
-85 => 4
-84 => 5
-83 => 6
-82 => 7
-81 => 8
-80 => 9
-79 => 0
-78 => .
-77 => ,
-76 => '
-75 => ?
-74 => !
-73 => @
-72 => _
-71 => -
-70 => A
-69 => B
-68 => C
-67 => D
-66 => E
-65 => F
-64 => G
-63 => H
-62 => I
-61 => J
-60 => K
-59 => L
-58 => M
-57 => N
-56 => O
-55 => P
-54 => Q
-53 => R
-52 => S
-51 => T
-50 => U
-49 => V
-48 => W
-47 => X
-46 => Y
-45 => Z
-44 => a
-43 => b
-42 => c
-41 => d
-40 => e
-39 => f
-38 => g
-37 => h
-36 => i
-35 => j
-34 => k
-33 => l
-32 => m
-31 => n
-30 => o
-29 => p
-28 => q
-27 => r
-26 => s
-25 => t
-24 => u
-23 => v
-22 => w
-21 => x
-20 => y
-19 => z
-18 => 1
-17 => 2
-16 => 3
-15 => 4
-14 => 5
-13 => 6
-12 => 7
-11 => 8
-10 => 9
-9 => 0
-8 => .
-7 => ,
-6 => '
-5 => ?
-4 => !
-3 => @
-2 => _
-1 => -
0 => A
1 => B
2 => C
3 => D
4 => E
5 => F
6 => G
7 => H
8 => I
9 => J
10 => K
11 => L
12 => M
13 => N
14 => O
15 => P
16 => Q
17 => R
18 => S
19 => T
20 => U
21 => V
22 => W
23 => X
24 => Y
25 => Z
26 => a
27 => b
28 => c
29 => d
30 => e
31 => f
32 => g
33 => h
34 => i
35 => j
36 => k
37 => l
38 => m
39 => n
40 => o
41 => p
42 => q
43 => r
44 => s
45 => t
46 => u
47 => v
48 => w
49 => x
50 => y
51 => z
52 => 1
53 => 2
54 => 3
55 => 4
56 => 5
57 => 6
58 => 7
59 => 8
60 => 9
61 => 0
62 => .
63 => ,
64 => '
65 => ?
66 => !
67 => @
68 => _
69 => -
70 => A
71 => B
72 => C
73 => D
74 => E
75 => F
76 => G
77 => H
78 => I
79 => J
80 => K
81 => L
82 => M
83 => N
84 => O
85 => P
86 => Q
87 => R
88 => S
89 => T
90 => U
91 => V
92 => W
93 => X
94 => Y
95 => Z
96 => a
97 => b
98 => c
99 => d
100 => e
101 => f
102 => g
103 => h
104 => i
105 => j
106 => k
107 => l
108 => m
109 => n
110 => o
111 => p
112 => q
113 => r
114 => s
115 => t
116 => u
117 => v
118 => w
119 => x
120 => y
121 => z
122 => 1
123 => 2
124 => 3
125 => 4
126 => 5
127 => 6
128 => 7
129 => 8
130 => 9
131 => 0
132 => .
133 => ,
134 => '
135 => ?
136 => !
137 => @
138 => _
139 => -
140 => A
141 => B
142 => C
143 => D
144 => E
145 => F
146 => G
147 => H
148 => I
149 => J
150 => K
151 => L
152 => M
153 => N
154 => O
155 => P
156 => Q
157 => R
158 => S
159 => T
160 => U
161 => V
162 => W
163 => X
164 => Y
165 => Z
166 => a
167 => b
168 => c
169 => d
170 => e
171 => f
172 => g
173 => h
174 => i
175 => j
176 => k
177 => l
178 => m
179 => n
180 => o
181 => p
182 => q
183 => r
184 => s
185 => t
186 => u
187 => v
188 => w
189 => x
190 => y
191 => z
192 => 1
193 => 2
194 => 3
195 => 4
196 => 5
197 => 6
198 => 7
199 => 8
```

Comment: Note, I changed the blank space to an @ symbol just so I could make sure it was there.

Answer (score 0):

Who ever commented, thank you. python when `IntI` got into the negatives it just looped back through the array. so i just had to add some statements to catch if IntI had gone bellow 0 or above the length of the array.

Comment: @Mike no need to say sorry :) and thanks for the help, i was ripping my hair out trying to figure out why it wasn't working.